# how to get field from the external Application and map it with salesforce object fields

Tags: apex, rest-api, map, wrapper-class

Hi I have a challenge in getting the data from external application and map it with sales force object fields.

Please find the progress I have made so far.

```
public class ZyncAPI {
public ZyncJSONWrapper getZyncData() {
    // Instantiate a new http object        
    Http h = new Http();        
    // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint        
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
    String endUrl = 'http://carrotcube-esb-zynx.cloudhub.io/zynx/PlanDefinition';
    req.setEndpoint(endUrl);        
    req.setMethod('GET');        
    // Send the request, and return a response        
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    ZyncJSONWrapper respWrap = (ZyncJSONWrapper)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), ZyncJSONWrapper.class);
    List<HealthCloudGA__EhrCondition__c> patientCondition = new List<HealthCloudGA__EhrCondition__c>(); 
    List<HealthCloudGA__CarePlanProblem__c> patientProblem = new List<HealthCloudGA__CarePlanProblem__c>();
    List<HealthCloudGA__CarePlanGoal__c> patientGoal = new List<HealthCloudGA__CarePlanGoal__c>();
    List<Interventions__c> patientIntervention = new List<Interventions__c>();
    //for(ZyncJSONWrapper.JSON2Apex i : respWrap.JSON2Apex.title){

   // }
    return respWrap;
```

}}

Wer have a wrapper class written for the Json response.

Please advise.

Comment: What is the challenge you are facing or what error are you facing?

Comment: @RedDevil I have been asked to map the fields with salesforce fields, which is where Im looking how to do mapping of external field with salesforce field. looking for an example

Comment: Would you mind sharing the wrapper class as well? If that wrapper class contains the instances of these Salesforce objects, then you can use those to map the values accordingly.

Comment: @NitishSinghal The wrapper class does not contain the instance of these salesforce Objects

Comment: Does your response have the field values which you want to map? If yes, in which structure they are. Because I thought wrapper might have those fields or reference to objects, but if it doesn't, then you may need to again look at the structure of the response.

Comment: @NitishSinghal please share your email I can share the Wrapper and Json structure.

Comment: nitishsinghal007@gmail.com

Comment: @NitishSinghal hi, I sent mail